# Editing text as a li in an unordered list

Tags: html, css, text, html-lists

So I got all excited to be able to position list items absolutely within an relatively positioned unordered list so I could add embedded media players and the like without questioning if they would appear in the right place on the page. But I'm wondering if I've painted myself in a corner, because now I have a list item positioned where I want to edit text. So I have a few lines of text in one list item, and want to take ONE LINE of that text and make it a hyperlink but when I go to add a link to it and preview it in a browser, the link doesn't appear to be active.

Is there a way to edit paragraphs in a list item, or a more efficient way to absolutely position text on a page?

Comment: Will probably need to see some markup/CSS.

Comment: Some example html of what you have now would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to absolutely position "text", you can only apply positioning to HTML elements. If you want to position a particular piece of text then put in its own `<p>` or `<div>` inside the `<li>` element. You can put whatever HTML elements you want inside an `<li>` element--it doesn't have to just be text.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your text in a `<span></span>` tag and position the span

Comment: I realized that what was happening is that I tried to circumnavigate making my navigation bar list items by making a clear .gif image the size of the page and hotspotting on top of it. But a genius friend of mine realized that was somehow short-circutting the other hyperlinks. Verrry interesting...